# Asp.net MVC try/catch does not redirect to custom error page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, custom-error-pages

I am using try/catch to catch and log errors to our database like this:

```
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            string actionName = this.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
            string controllerName = this.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();

            ErrorLogger.Log(ex.GetType().Name, controllerName + "/"+ actionName, MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, ex.Message, ex.StackTrace);
        }
```

This works fine, but my problem is the the custom error page does not display when the error is handled by the try/catch so the user does not know that an error has occurred.  However, if an unhandled error occurs outside of any try/catch block, the custom page displays.

I have an ErrorPage Controller:

```
public class ErrorPageController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Oops (int statusCode, Exception exception)
    {
        return View("Error");
    }
}
```

This is my FilterConfig:

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    }
}
```

This is in my Global.asax:

```
    public void Application_Error(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Exception exception = Server.GetLastError();
        Server.ClearError();

        var routeData = new RouteData();
        routeData.Values.Add("controller", "ErrorPage");
        routeData.Values.Add("action", "Oops");
        routeData.Values.Add("exception", exception);

        if (exception.GetType() == typeof(HttpException))
        {
            routeData.Values.Add("statusCode", ((HttpException)exception).GetHttpCode());
        }
        else
        {
            routeData.Values.Add("statusCode", 500);
        }

        Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
        IController controller = new ErrorPageController();
        controller.Execute(new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(Context), routeData));
        Response.End();
    }
```

This is in my webconfig:

```
        <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/ErrorPage/Oops"/>
```

Comment: Why would it? You aren’t issuing a redirection nor are you re-throwing in your catch block.

Comment: So there is no way to "globally" redirect to the error page if using the catch?  I have to add a redirect to every catch block in the app?

Comment: Yes, but why catch it in the first place if you have a global error handler? Also, you **should not** issue a HTTP 3xx redirection to show an error message. Error messages should be in direct response to a failed request and served with an appropriate HTTP 4xx-5xx response status code. I’m glad they removed redirection-based error messages in ASP.NET Core, it should never have been added in the first place.

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about as this is all new to me, and I have no idea how to proceed, but at least you responded so that I know someone at least looked at my issue.

Comment: BTW, you should use `Exception.ToString()` to get an exception report as that will include details of `InnerException`, but your `ErrorLogger.Log` method doesn't do that, so you're missing out on useful exception details.